# How to increase migration and seeding speed in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

My database migrations and seeding speed is super slow. How to increase the speed of it? I'm frustrated because of this. It takes round about 20 mins for that.
I have about 30 migrations and most data types are int,varchar and enum.

I realized that it takes much time in migrations,seeding is working normal.

Comment: How many tables are you seeding, and how many rows do they have each? What sort of data are you adding to them - ints or blobs? _Don't reply to me, please edit your question - thanks, it may stop it closing_.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Looking at the migrations themselves is probably needed, they might do some things slow. You should not have to migrate everything every time though, only the latest changes. `php artisan migrate` should remember all previous migrations.